pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:00:1b.4
I have a recurring error that I have noticed in the logs of Ubuntu 24.04 that I can't track down ! But it seems that all my PCIe cards seem to function correctly,infact at the moment I'm using FreeBSD and I don't see that error when I issue the command "dmesg -a".
[  408.981747] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: PCIe Bus Error:  severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  408.981748] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4:   device [8086:a32c] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  408.981749] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4:    [ 0] RxErr                 (First)
[  408.981757] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:00:1b.4
[  408.981767] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER: found no error details for 0000:00:1b.4

It seems the same bug reported here :
https://forums.unraid.net/topic/82644-pcie-error/
but I'm not using UnRaid. I want to understand if the error is related to Ubuntu 24.04 or if it is an hardware fault.
What I see on Ubuntu is the space on the disk that's 0 byte because that error is flooding the screen and it is written very fast on the log file and it has eaten all the space available. I can't use Ubuntu until I understand how to fix it.

Normally those notices mean there's some sort of hardware fault or issues in the PCI bus. Does the system not work when you see this error, or are you just concerned that it spams the logs?

It works,but it spams the log so heavy that it has eaten all the space available and I can't use it anymore. In FreeBSD the error is not visible,so I'm inclined to think that there is a bug in Ubuntu more than an hardware error.
